# How do I solve javac compiler error, "package com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.model does not exist"?

Tags: java, xml, compiler-errors, jaxb, javac

I'm seeing a bizarre error when I do a Maven build, launched through Jenkins, using Java 6.  I get errors during my test-compile phase, which are

```
[ERROR] /scratch/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/myproject/src/test/java/org/mainco/subco/ebook/mvc/  CorrelationUpdateControllerTest.java:[77,48] error: package com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.model does not exist
[ERROR] /scratch/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/myproject/src/test/java/org/mainco/subco/ebook/mvc/CorrelationUpdateControllerTest.java:[77,48] error: package com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.model does not exist
[INFO] 2 errors
```

The errors relate in no way to line 77, referenced above.  That line is

```
public class CorrelationUpdateControllerTest extends AbstractNTsubcoTests
```

I'm using the jaxb-api, v 2.2.9 if that matters.  The Maven dependency is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

A more detailed output of what's happening is below ...

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building subco Admin Module 16.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-oxm/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-oxm-3.1.1.RELEASE.pom
```

Downloaded: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-oxm/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-oxm-3.1.1.RELEASE.pom (4 KB at 23.5 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-webmvc-portlet/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-portlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.pom
    Downloaded: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-webmvc-portlet/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-portlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.pom (4 KB at 42.6 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom
    Downloaded: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom (4 KB at 133.4 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom
    Downloaded: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom (4 KB at 47.5 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-config-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom
    Downloaded: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-config-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom (4 KB at 41.5 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-taglibs/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-taglibs-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom
    Downloaded: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-taglibs/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-taglibs-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom (4 KB at 16.5 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-acl/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-acl-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom
    Downloaded: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-acl/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-acl-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom (4 KB at 145.5 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-oxm/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-oxm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
    Downloading: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-webmvc-portlet/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-portlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
    Downloading: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
    Downloading: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
    Downloading: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-config-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
    Downloaded: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-oxm/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-oxm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar (72 KB at 1372.9 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-taglibs/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-taglibs-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
    Downloaded: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-taglibs/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-taglibs-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar (21 KB at 176.6 KB/sec)
    Downloading: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-acl/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-acl-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar
    Downloaded: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-config-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar (199 KB at 1156.6 KB/sec)
    Downloaded: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar (248 KB at 1369.5 KB/sec)
    Downloaded: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-acl/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-acl-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar (78 KB at 2678.2 KB/sec)
    Downloaded: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar (333 KB at 1721.7 KB/sec)
    Downloaded: http://repo.ourrepo.com/content/groups/public/org/springframework/spring-webmvc-portlet/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-portlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar (187 KB at 621.6 KB/sec)
mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1(default-clean)
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ myproject ---
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1(default-clean)
    [debug] execute contextualize
mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5(default-resources)
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ myproject ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 7 resources
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5(default-resources)
mojoStarted org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2(default)
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:write-project-properties (default) @ myproject ---
mojoSucceeded org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2(default)
mojoStarted org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5(drop-db-before-test-if-any)
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (drop-db-before-test-if-any) @ myproject ---
    [INFO] Skip sql execution
mojoSucceeded org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5(drop-db-before-test-if-any)
mojoStarted org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5(create-test-db)[INFO] Skip sql execution

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (create-test-db) @ myproject ---
```

mojoSucceeded org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5(create-test-db)
mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2(default-compile)
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ myproject ---
    [INFO] Compiling 40 source files to /scratch/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/myproject/target/classes
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2(default-compile)
    [debug] execute contextualize
mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5(default-testResources)
    [INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Copying 10 resources
```

mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5(default-testResources)
mojoStarted org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5(create-stored-proc)[INFO] Skip sql execution

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sql-maven-plugin:1.5:execute (create-stored-proc) @ myproject ---
```

mojoSucceeded org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.5(create-stored-proc)
mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7(unzip-liquibase-archive)
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (unzip-liquibase-archive) @ myproject ---
    [INFO] Executing tasks

```
main:
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7(unzip-liquibase-archive)[INFO] Executed tasks

mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7(format-liquibase-files)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (format-liquibase-files) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
[INFO] Executed tasks
mojoSucceeded org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7(format-liquibase-files)
mojoStarted com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer:1.5.1(create-init-db-test-scripts)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- replacer:1.5.1:replace (create-init-db-test-scripts) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Replacement run on 1 file.
mojoSucceeded com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer:1.5.1(create-init-db-test-scripts)
mojoStarted org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2(default-testCompile)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to /scratch/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/myproject/target/test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /scratch/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/myproject/src/test/java/org/mainco/subco/ebook/mvc/  CorrelationUpdateControllerTest.java:[77,48] error: package com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.model does not exist
[ERROR] /scratch/jenkins/workspace/subco/subco/myproject/src/test/java/org/mainco/subco/ebook/mvc/  CorrelationUpdateControllerTest.java:[77,48] error: package com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.model does not exist
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
mojoFailed org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2(default-testCompile)
projectFailed org.mainco.subco:myproject:16.0.0-SNAPSHOT
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
```

Comment: This is totally unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `com.sun.tools.internal.ws` it look like you are working with web services and some of the JAX-WS tools, like the `wsgen` tool.

JAX-WS tools are part of the Java Development Kit (JDK) - it's in the `tools.jar which can't be found in JRE.
Not likely the cause, but you should check if Jenkins is using a JRE.

More likely is you are doing this on a Linux workstation/server and you don't have the Oracle's JDK installed. OpenJDK probably doesn't have Sun's "private" tools/implementations.

Comment: I'm not suing JAX-WS.  I only want the JAXB api to turn some of my POJOs into XML strings.  Is the only way to compile JAXB to have the tools.jar in the JRE, as you suggest?

Comment: I am not sure why JAXB would do this. You could try commenting out that part of the code and run Maven just to confirm if that is what is causing the issue.